# 3 speed clutch converted from steering column to floor with universal shifter

Tags: clutch, clutch-cylinder

I have a 3 on the tree. Converted to floor clutch issue. I think. I was driving and went to take the The truck out of Gear and my clutch Went all the way to the floor any loud sound and clang happened. I didn't have trouble getting into gear and had to push it a few feet until it Slipped into gear. I'm from then on, I pushed the clutch in and would push really hard on the shifter and it would almost engage but not fully I had to shut the truck off. Put it in gear, what's it? Went relatively easy and then have someone.  Pull start me while I'm gear. What could this be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

From the symptoms, your clutch is not disconnecting from engagement with the flywheel.

If you have a clutch cable, it probably broke or came disconnected. If it's a hydraulic clutch, the slave cylinder may have popped off the housing.

Comment: It's all linkage: shifter and clutch. Knim going to check those two suggestions. Is there anything special I should know (such as a specific tool ill need) before I dive in the s@##

Comment: @SeanLegino Specific tool: a helper to operate the clutch pedal while you look for the broken or disconnected part of the linkage.

Comment: the shifter is a separate thing from the clutch, the two are not connected.